# Magento 2: Footer Links, add more, sort into blocks with headings?

Tags: magento, magento2

Over the past few days I have been trying to figure out how to modify the footer links in Magento 2 to no avail. I'd like to style them similar to Magento 1.9, where there were multiple blocks of links, each with different headings. What is the best way to approach this? It appears that the default links are added through php files of various modules. I don't want to modify the php of core files to accomplish this... Is a block going to have to be created from scratch? Worried about this, Magento 2 has not made anything easy thus far... Hoping that what I am asking could perhaps be solved through XML...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to add custom links in footer of Magento2 website then you need to do following changes:
add below code in default.xml fo your Magento2 theme:

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="2custom-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Custom Links</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">page-url</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Please apply it and let me know if you still getting this issue.